# Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Tags: django

I want to install django. I have the following instructions to do this:

```
    wget "http://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.4/tarball/" -O Django-1.4.tar.gz
    tar xzvf Django-1.4.tar.gz
    cd Django-1.4
    sudo python setup.py install
```

when I run the second line (i.e., `tar xzvf Django-1.4.tar.gz`) then I get the following message:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Is there any problem? Please help me.

Comment: Probably: wget --no-cookies --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.djangoproject.com" ...

Answer (score 2):

The error can mean 2 things depending on what file you downloaded. In the normal sense, when users download a file **not ending with .gz** it means the file is not a gzip format.

The other case is when the downloaded file is corrupted. I took my time to download the `http://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.4/tarball/`  file and it works with the line you are mentioning so it must mean the file was downloaded and somehow got corrupted. Download the file again.

Just to add that I had a problem about a year ago, similar to this, it was a memory problem. One of the memory slots was damaged (Memtest verified this). This is of course an extreme case, but wanted to mention it just in case.

What I would suggest is to do the following:

1. Download file like this: `wget http://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.4/tarball/ -O Django-1.4.tar.gz`
   (No double quotes, just in case when copied from a website, they were the bbcode double codes and not the common ones used in the terminal)
2. Decompress like you mentioned: `tar xzvf Django-1.4.tar.gz`

See if that works.

Comment: do the following, on your browser, go to http://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.4/tarball/ it will automatically start downloading the file. Test with that.

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950839/tar-error-is-not-recoverable-exiting-now

```
mv Doctrine-1.2.0.tgz Doctrine-1.2.0.tar.gz
gunzip Doctrine-1.2.0.tar.gz
tar xf Doctrine-1.2.0.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

#### *Please* forget about running `setup.py` from source!

Use **`pip`** to install Python packages. It's *so much* easier and preferred over easy_install / setup.py ([Why use pip over easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3220404/1254292)).

It's as easy as:

1. Install `pip` by installing the Ubuntu package: [python-pip [image: Install python-pip]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/python-pip)
2. Install any package from PyPI like this:

   ```
    sudo pip install Django
   ```

Done. Replace `Django` with any other package from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).